# Set MySql time zone dynamically with JVM -Duser.timezone in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I've a Ubuntu 16 server in "IST" TZ.
MySQL (v5.7) server in "IST" TZ.
Spring-boot (v2), Java (v1.8) jar in "America/Los_Angeles" TZ. Setting from -Duser.timezone arg.

Problem: As my Java Date obj is in "America/Los_Angeles" TZ, fetching MySQL data was not working as MySQL date was a day behind from java date.
Found the above difference in Java when logged actual date obj (query parameter obj to be used) without passing it to query and the java object fetched from MySQL after select *.

Solution:
Added "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = America/Los_Angeles" in application.properties. It worked fine as expected.

Questions:
1. Is there any way that i can align MySQL TZ with the spring boot Java application TZ, passed with "-Duser.timezone" arg dynamically, i.e, by picking the value from the argument?
2. In MySQL DB, can I check each connection's timezone? Similar like in, I can see the connection list from "show processlist" query.

Comment: You need to start using `UTC`, regardless of where the service/server is located at. The rest of the things you can do is going to be a _dancing_ all the time to get it right.

Comment: @x80486 Thanks for your time. Got the idea. Running in UTC seems ideal. Will work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use *java.time* classes to avoid your time zone issues.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
myPreparedStatament.setObject( … , java.time.OffsetDateTime.now( z ) ) ;   // Persisting
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;   // Retrieval
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;                           // Adjust into the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). Same moment, same point on the timeline.
```

## *java.time*

> my Java Date obj

The `Date` classes (`java.util.Date` & `java.sql.Date`) are both terrible, now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

> I've a Ubuntu 16 server in "IST" TZ.

FYI, servers are generally best set to a default time zone of UTC (GMT), an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. Be aware that the host OS has its own default time zone, and the JVM has its own default. And middleware such as interactive session with your database may have its own current default time zone.

As a Java programmer, you should never rely on the current default time zone. Any code in any thread of any app within the JVM can change the default at any moment during runtime. So, better to specify the expected/desired time zone.

> "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = America/Los_Angeles"

If you exchange *java.time* classes with your database rather than using strings or the legacy date-time classes, you will not need this setting. [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2, later versions of Hibernate, and [JPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) 2.2 all require support for *java.time* objects.

> Is there any way that i can align MySQL TZ with the spring boot Java application TZ, passed with "-Duser.timezone" arg dynamically, i.e, by picking the value from the argument?

If you exchange *java.time* objects with the database, this question becomes moot, the problem goes away, and your life gets easier.

> In MySQL DB, can I check each connection's timezone? Similar like in, I can see the connection list from "show processlist" query.

Ditto, use *java.time* objects and the question becomes moot.

### Example code

#### Date only, without time-of-day, without time zone

For a column type akin to the SQL standard `DATE`, use `java.time.LocalDate`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
myPreparedStatament.setObject( … , LocalDate.now( z ) ) ;      // Persisting
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;  // Retrieval
```

#### Moment, a point on the timeline

For a column type akin to the SQL standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, use [`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) (optionally [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) or [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
myPreparedStatament.setObject( … , java.time.OffsetDateTime.now( z ) ) ;      // Persisting
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;  // Retrieval
```

#### Not a moment, just date and time-of-day

For a column type akin to the SQL standard `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, use [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). Be aware: Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC means this data type cannot represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline.

```
myPreparedStatament.setObject( … , LocalDateTime.of( 2020 , Month.MAY , 15 , 22 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) ;  // Persisting
LocalDateTime let = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;                           // Retrieval
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Thank you @basil-bourque for your time. I did try migrating from legacy Date class to modern java.time class after referring your few answers on other posts. But had errors/ value mismatches, so reverted back and decided to run like the solution I've mentioned as fix needed was very urgent. May be I had done it wrong while migrating as Its the first time i'm dealing with TimeZones. Surely will try the way as you have suggested above.